# Get localized user roles

Tags: localization

I have a settings page that shows the users wordpress role. I am using `wp_get_current_user()->roles` get that list. However, that list appears in English, and often my users have their locale set to something other than English.

Is there a way to get the users role in a localized string?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `translate_user_role($role)` function.

More details:
[translate_user_role()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/translate_user_role/)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26187405/13466558